# Regression interaction terms in stata

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, interaction, stata, binary-data

I am currently studying the relationship between having a supervisory job and having traditional values when it comes to child care (woman staying home). I want to find the relationship with differences in gender. So woman probably have a negative correlation and men a positive one.

It is logical to add interaction terms `traditional value * female` and `traditional value * men` to find the difference in "stata"?

Answer (score 0):

If you think *a priori* that gender will modify the effect of traditional values on having a supervisory job, than yes, add the interaction term. The p value given for the interaction term will tell you whether there is a significant difference in the way gender modifies traditional values effect on having a supervisory position.